# Implementing loginform with react issue

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement SpringBoot Security's LoginForm and have it talk with my react application. I'm currently following the tutorial below:

[Baeldung  Spring Security Login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

I've reached the part where it talks about implementing the configuration for the LoginForm itself. It states the following code:

```
http
      // ...
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login.html")
      .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
      .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
      .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
      .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
      .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
      .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
```

The main part of that to take away is the `authenticationFailureHandler()` and the `logoutSuccessHandler()` methods.

Neither of them exist within `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, nor does the article actually implement them. Do I have to create a customer version of both in this instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the bottom of the article, they provide a link to [their GitHub project](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-login) containing all of the code from the article.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/6c0bb2925d889194016fe0fd23d33f92fdb0dc2b/spring-security-modules/spring-security-web-login/src/main/java/com/baeldung/security/config/SecSecurityConfig.java) to file of this project, containing the code you mention.

But in short, they do implement a custom version of it.

Also, it seems that tihs question was accidentally mistakenly tagged with `react`.